# .each + .click (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I try to run this code:

```js
$('a').each( function(index, element) {
 element.click(function(){
  console.log('hit');
 });
});
```

It doesn't work, but if I code this one:

```js
$('a').each( function() {
 $(this).click(function(){
  console.log('hit');
 });
});
```

Everything is ok, someone can help me please? Why is not working when I use ***element***

PD: I know that this solution is the best but I would like to know why is not working before

```js
$('a')click(function(){
  console.log('hit');
});
```

Comment: jQuery does not make the assumption that for an iterator over the stack results that the user will always want the elements to be in a jQuery object.  If it did, then it would have to create a new jQuery object for each element passed in.  This is incurred overhead that would be unavoidable for it's built in methods.  Instead, it defaults to providing the raw dom element and if you do need the element in a jQuery object, you can put it in one.  But at that point it is your choice to encur that overhead and you are in full control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `$(element).click(...` because `element` is a DOM Element, not a jQuery object.

```js
$('a').each( function(index, element) {
 $(element).click(function(){
  console.log('hit');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a>foo</a>
<p><a>bar</a>
<p><a>baz</a>
```

There is actually a `click` method on native Elements, but it serves a different purpose; it invokes a "click" event instead of binding a handler.

---

And of course to do this without large dependencies, and using modern syntax, it could look like this:

```js
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {         
  element.addEventListener("click", handler)
}

function handler() {
  console.log('hit');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a>foo</a></p>
<p><a>bar</a></p>
<p><a>baz</a></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use addEventListener

```
$('a').each( function(index, element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log('hit');
    }); 
});
```